# What is best practice for organizing Django REST Framework serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am working on migrating a legacy REST api to Django REST framework. Many responses from contain nested serializers, for example:

```py
class TemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     colors = ColorSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
     fonts = FontSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
     property_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Property.objects.all())
...
     class Meta:
          model = Template
          fields = '__all__'

class ColorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     swatch = SwatchSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
          model = Color
          fields = '__all__'

# and so forth, just imagine several serializers with fields that are read only or write only etc
```

Currently I was have all serializers in `my_app/serializers.py` and the `serializers.py` file has grown way too large and disorganized. In that file, a django model usually has several versions of serializers, for example, the `list` view method may have a different serializer than `retrieve` and `create` may have a different serializer than `update`, etc. So a single ViewSet may have 4-5 different serializers. Also, the nested serializers, like the `ColorSerializer` above, may have different versions based on requirements of the response when its nested in another serializer versus when `GET /colors` endpoint is called.

With that being said, I want to start organizing/refactoring things for readability to try to be more DRY. I'm aware the API is poorly designed, but redesigning is not an option due to the amount of time it will take. What is the best way forward to clean up my `serializers.py` file and Serializer classes? Any help and opinion is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

create **serializers** name package inside the App. Create a separate serializer file for every model of that app. Don't forget to import the serializer in the ****init**.py** file. With the bifurcation of serializer files based on the model, it will become easy to find serializers related to specific model API.

Comment: I see, but that doesn't solve for the issue if I have several serializers for the same model. If it does, what's the best way to organize multiple serializers for the same model in a module structure?

Comment: I don't recommend this approach. The only remaining way now is to differentiate the serializer based on actions such as listing, creating, and updating. Please understand that splitting code is only For clarity and readability. This helps developers easily navigate the code and enhances understanding for others. However, avoid excessive splitting to maintain a balance between organization and complexity.